# How do you pass a NotesDocument / NotesViewEntry Collection into a Custom Control via custom property?

Tags: xpages

I want to have a custom control that works on whatever documents I decide to pass to it.  What's the best way of doing that?

Assuming that you can't pass the collection directly...  should a function be created to convert the collection to a hashMap or vector of UNID's?

Is there another way?

Thanks

Comment: I'd say go with ArrayList instead of a Vector.

Comment: Thank you!  I tried java.lang.Object first and that worked.  Interestingly if you try to use this for a repeat it looks like it's auto converted to UNIDs...  but they're not strings. so you need to do a .toString() to make it usable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing NotesDocument and/or NotesDocumentCollection objects to the Custom Control works fine. Just set the Custom Control's property type as java.lang.Object. By this you can transfer what ever objects to the Custom Control.

Answer (score 7):

If you instead pass a data source, you'll get recycle-safe objects transferred to the Custom Control.

For example, if the XPage defines a document data source, and you pass a reference to that data source to the CC, the Java object being transferred is a DominoDocument, which is a recycle-safe wrapper around the "back end" document. Passing the document directly risks that the linked C object will get orphaned between requests.

Similarly, passing a reference to a view data source provides the CC a DominoView, which is essentially a recycle-safe wrapper around a back end ViewEntryCollection.

For most use cases, you can get away with just passing the back end object directly, but passing the data source is far safer.