# Can dataContext return a NotesViewEntry Collection?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

This is a follow-up to my previous post at [In a SSJS button I have got a NotesViewEntryCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25856437/in-a-ssjs-button-i-have-got-a-notesviewentrycollection)

So I have a Go button that takes a value from a field and returns a viewEntryCollection so I see how I could compute this in a dataContext. I added this to my page:

```
    <xp:this.dataContexts>
        <xp:dataContext var="veCol">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var vw:NotesView = database.getView("vwCompanies");
var thisVeCol:NotesViewEntryCollection = vw.getAllEntriesByKey(viewScope.get("vsCompany"),false);
if (thisVeCol.getCount() == 0){
    //get back to the page don't pass veCol probably need to do more than this
    return "";
}else{
    //the repeat is not rendered if false Go button does a partial refreash on the panelRepeat
    //think it will need to a partial refresh on this dataContext as well
    viewScope.put("vsDisplayRepeat", true);
    return thisVeCol;
}}]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:dataContext>
    </xp:this.dataContexts>
```

Then my repeat would just bind to veCol and should give me what I want. I think I would have to check to see if vsCompany is set in this code.

Now I have read contradicting statements as to wheter the dataContext can be used in this way to contain a Notes Object because of Serialization.

Would this concept work in practice? Does my code do what I think it should?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no. Other than a bug in the code (you're missing "()" after "getCount" early on - I believe that the current form will always evaluate false since it's comparing a class (I *think*) to 0, but who knows with SSJS?), that code will likely do what you expect.

However, it will probably do it far more often than you'd expect, much to the detriment of your page's speeds. #{}-bound dataContexts are evaluated many times during page evaluation. Sven Hasselbach went into this in excellent detail (http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1112) and the upshot is that a normal load of a page that uses it once will calculate it three times and a refresh could be eleven times.

${}-bound dataContexts don't have this problem, as they're evaluated just once per XPage, but they would indeed run into the Serialization problem you describe. Probably your best bet would be to switch to using an `<xp:dominoView/>` data source with a `categoryFilter` or, if that's impractical for some reason, pre-reading in the view entry data into a `List<Map<String, Object>>` (which would be easier with the OpenNTF API). If you do the latter, be careful about `DateTime`s.

Comment: jesse - thanks for the input actually in this case using a domino view and pass the 'key' to the DominoView. I could do a getAllDocumentsBy Key to determine how many hits there are. If there are 0 then return a message "None Found" if == 1 then I open that document for input if > 1 show the repeat. 
However, I have another instance where it would be really neat to be able to pass a viewEntryCollection. Because the selection requires the user to enter some information I guess I could use a ${} bound dataContext and have the Go but do a reloadPage which should recalculate the dataContext oncs.

Comment: In most cases the simple solution is the best solution. Bound the repeat to a DominoView with the first column sorted by company then added Filter By Column and set that to a viewScope vsCompany. The user enters the first few characters of the company name and presses Go button. The Go button does a partial refresh on the repeat. in my Go button I do a getAllDocumentsByKey(key,false) if the dc.getCount() == 0 return a message, if == 1 open the document if greater than 1 set a viewScope.vsShowRepeat = true, do the refresh. Fast clean and neat. Thanks Jesse